# How to generated random number from lognormal distribution with known parameters mu and sigma?

Tags: java, random, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I have a known parameters mu and sigma for 
lognormal distribution, and I don not know the lower and upper bound or interval for the random variable. 
I know (Random.nextGaussian() * sigma ) + mu used to generat random variat for normal distribution with mu and sigma parameters. However, how can I generate a random number from the lognormal distribution with known mu and sigma using Java? Thank you.

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use apache commons math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/LogNormalDistribution.html) to create a LogNormalDistribution.

```
    Double mu = 0.0;
    Double sigma = 0.0;
    LogNormalDistribution logNormal = new LogNormalDistribution(sigma, mu);
    System.out.println("Random Value : " + logNormal.sample());
```

Comment: It works perfectly using logNormal.simulate(). Thanks a lot